# Why setting __set__ function for method descriptor does not make it data-descriptor?

Tags: python, python-descriptors

I've started reading about descriptors in Python and created small test to see whether the order of attribute access is same as it is described. As I understand when attribute of object is accessed it is looked in following order:

1. in `type(instance).__dict__` - if data descriptor of given name is present, its `__get__`method call is returned
2. in `instance.__dict__`
3. if non-data descriptor is present in `type(instance).__dict__` then `__get__` method call is returned
4. `__getattr__` is called.

Now, if method is non-data descriptor of type instance of given class, than by giving this descriptor `__set__` function/method it would make it data descriptor, hence overwriting such function could be for example blocked or manipulated. Unfortunately that does not work and my question is simply: why is that a case? Does Python "marks" data and non-data descriptors at class initialization or I've done something wrong?

```
class A:
    def d(self):
        pass

def __set__(self, instance, value):
    print("Nothing to see here...")



A.__dict__['d'].__set__ = __set__
a = A()
a.d = "value"
print(a.d) # prints "value" instead of <bound method ...>
```

Comment: Specifically, magic methods of an object are looked up on `type(obj)`, which for pretty much everything should be `obj.__class__`. This question is a duplicate of many, many other questions.

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question, because there's some confusion about *which class* the lookup is taking place in. The questioner was thinking about the lookups in class A, but the issue is with the lookup of `__get__` in the descriptor's class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A.__dict__['d'].__set__ = __set__`, which is just a complicated way of writing `A.d.__set__ = __set__` in this case, is setting a magic method on the *instance*.

This is not working in Python, magic methods are only looked up on the type. And you can't set it on the type, because the type is just the builtin function type here.

However, it is possible to change a non-data descriptor into a data descriptor dynamically:

```
>>> class MyDescriptor:
...     def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
...         return 'foo'
... 
>>> class A:
...     f = MyDescriptor()
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.f
'foo'
>>> a.f = 'foo2'
>>> a.f
'foo2'
>>> MyDescriptor.__set__ = lambda self, instance, value: None
>>> a.f  # now the descriptor takes precedence again over a.__dict__
'foo'
```